# Carrierwave / Fog not seeing Heroku environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, carrierwave, fog

I'm upgrading from Ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3.2.14 to Ruby 2.2.0 / Rails 4.2.1 and everything works on my development system. When pushing to Heroku, I get `ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key` however those environment variables are set.

```
~/documents/coding$ heroku config -a vupgrade
=== vupgrade Config Vars
....
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:            ...XYZ...
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:        ...XYZ...
....
```

After forking my staging system, the (more complete) output of the push is as follows:

```
~/documents/coding$ git push upgrade upgrade:master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 9950, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5166/5166), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9950/9950), 82.90 MiB | 748.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 9950 (delta 7130), reused 6420 (delta 4535)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.0
-----> Installing gsl
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
       Fetching https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/rb-gsl.git
       Fetching git://github.com/bearded-nemesis/heroku-rglpk.git
       Fetching https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/joule.git
       Fetching https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/ride_parser.git
       Fetching https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/top_efforts.git
       Fetching https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/RubyPeaks.git
       Using rake (10.4.2)
       Installing CFPropertyList (2.3.0)
       Installing i18n (0.7.0)
       Installing thread_safe (0.3.5)
       Installing minitest (5.5.1)
       Installing builder (3.2.2)
       Installing mini_portile (0.6.2)
       Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing arel (6.0.0)
       Installing encryptor (1.3.0)
       Installing rack (1.6.0)
       Installing execjs (2.3.0)
       Installing cancancan (1.10.1)
       Installing sass (3.4.13)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.9.1)
       Installing thor (0.19.1)
       Installing daemons (1.1.9)
       Installing orm_adapter (0.5.0)
       Installing excon (0.44.4)
       Installing fastercsv (1.5.5)
       Installing formatador (0.2.5)
       Installing net-ssh (2.9.2)
       Installing multi_json (1.11.0)
       Installing bcrypt (3.1.10)
       Installing inflecto (0.0.2)
       Installing ipaddress (0.8.0)
       Installing json (1.8.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing multi_xml (0.5.5)
       Installing systemu (2.6.4)
       Installing netrc (0.10.3)
       Installing narray (0.6.1.1)
       Installing nori (2.4.0)
       Using heroku-rglpk (0.2.1) from git://github.com/bearded-nemesis/heroku-rglpk.git (at master)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Installing newrelic_rpm (3.10.0.279)
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
       Installing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing rolify (4.0.0)
       Installing eventmachine (1.0.5)
       Installing session (3.2.0)
       Using ride_parser (0.0.2) from https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/ride_parser.git (at master)
       Using trainingpeaks (0.0.0) from https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/RubyPeaks.git (at master)
       Using top_efforts (0.0.2) from https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/top_efforts.git (at master)
       Installing unf_ext (0.0.6)
       Installing switch_user (0.9.5)
       Installing will_paginate (3.0.7)
       Installing gyoku (1.2.2)
       Installing fission (0.5.0)
       Installing mail (2.6.3)
       Installing attr_encrypted (1.3.3)
       Installing pg (0.18.1)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.3)
       Installing httpi (2.3.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.3.0)
       Installing figaro (1.1.0)
       Installing warden (1.2.3)
       Installing net-scp (1.2.1)
       Installing heroku-api (0.3.18)
       Installing tzinfo (1.2.2)
       Installing autoprefixer-rails (5.1.7)
       Installing macaddr (1.7.1)
       Installing fog-json (1.0.0)
       Installing rest-client (1.7.3)
       Installing rails_12factor (0.0.3)
       Installing sprockets (2.12.3)
       Installing thin (1.5.1)
       Installing rush (0.6.8)
       Installing unf (0.1.4)
       Installing will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.1)
       Installing fog-core (1.29.0)
       Installing activesupport (4.2.1)
       Installing tzinfo-data (1.2015.1)
       Installing bootstrap-sass (3.3.3)
       Installing uuid (2.3.7)
       Installing stripe (1.20.1)
       Installing fog-brightbox (0.7.1)
       Installing fog-sakuracloud (1.0.0)
       Installing fog-serverlove (0.1.1)
       Installing fog-softlayer (0.4.1)
       Installing fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.0)
       Installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
       Installing fog-vmfusion (0.0.1)
       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
       Installing globalid (0.3.3)
       Installing activemodel (4.2.1)
       Installing delayed_job (4.0.6)
       Installing stripe_event (1.5.0)
       Installing loofah (2.0.1)
       Installing akami (1.2.2)
       Installing fog-xml (0.1.1)
       Using joule (1.0.4) from https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/joule.git (at master)
       Installing httparty (0.13.3)
       Installing rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
       Installing wasabi (3.3.0)
       Installing carrierwave (0.10.0)
       Installing activerecord (4.2.1)
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
       Installing fog-atmos (0.1.0)
       Installing fog-ecloud (0.0.2)
       Installing fog-profitbricks (0.0.1)
       Installing fog-radosgw (0.0.3)
       Installing fog-aws (0.1.1)
       Installing fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
       Installing fog-terremark (0.0.4)
       Installing fog-voxel (0.0.2)
       Installing savon (2.8.1)
       Installing delayed_job_active_record (4.0.3)
       Installing actionview (4.2.1)
       Installing strava-api-v3 (0.1.0)
       Installing actionpack (4.2.1)
       Installing railties (4.2.1)
       Installing sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
       Installing simple_form (3.1.0.rc2)
       Installing coffee-rails (4.1.0)
       Installing responders (2.1.0)
       Installing jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.4)
       Installing fog (1.28.0)
       Installing jquery-rails (4.0.3)
       Installing devise (3.4.1)
       Using gsl (1.14.7) from https://ccd14907bc3e94a7f9e2366ad113d7c89b88eeb2:x-oauth-basic@github.com/rvizza/rb-gsl.git (at master)
       Installing activejob (4.2.1)
       Installing actionmailer (4.2.1)
       Installing rails (4.2.1)
       Installing workless (1.2.3)
       Installing spinjs-rails (1.4)
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from httparty:
       When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
       Bundle completed (465.41s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Removing  (extensions)
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.29.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.29.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.29.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.29.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:25:in `new'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_b9f857cd429cef497f20b494b19ece85/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:vupgrade.git
 ! [remote rejected] upgrade -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:vupgrade.git'
```

Any idea why fog is not seeing the environment variables?

***UPDATE***

Forgot to mention that I do have a `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb` file as follows:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider              => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region                => ENV['AWS_REGION']
  }

  if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
    config.storage = :fog
  else
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
    config.root = "#{Rails.root}/tmp"
  end

  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  config.fog_directory = ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']
end
```

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Could you share more of the stacktrace? I think it could help to give a bit more context of where the issue might lie. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing @geemus. I just included the entire trace. Thanks for taking a look. I'm still baffled at this one.

Comment: Thanks, it's not apparent to me even now...

Comment: Weird. I don't think it should be a timing issue on heroku (the env should be there up front). Do you call or change `Carrierwave.configure` any where else? ie maybe that config gets overwritten somewhere? It looks fine in isolation, you could also try just adding some `puts` statements to the top of the initializer, which should give you just-in-time info on what the values are from ENV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that I am using a custom buildpack, which is possibly the cause of some of these issues. When first encountering the issue above, I didn't think this was relevant, but the more I've researched the more I think it is relevant...Mainly because I can't imagine that others have gotten past these issues with the same kludgy fixes I outline below. With that as the caveat, on to the answer...

With the removal of `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` from Rails 4, all initializers are apparently run during precompile. If they include ENV references, well then you have a problem because those ENV values are not present during Heroku asset precompilation. In addition, during precompile Devise will attempt to connect to the database, which won't be available either.

I chose to fix these issues by conditionally running the initializers that include ENV references as follows:

```
unless ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'].blank?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
    ....
    }
  end
end
```

While not crazy about the idea, I also decided the locally precompile my assets and commit them to source code control. This seems to prevent Heroku from precompiling assets on the server and therefore fixes the problem.

Thanks @geemus and @joao for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using CarrierWaveUpload gem you should have this in an initializer.

Example: `/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],                        
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID']
    #Other options ommited
  }
```

You can see the all the parameters required here:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3

Comment: Sorry about that @joao, I forgot to mention that I do have a carrierwave initializer, and just updated my question with its contents.

Comment: Sorry @RobertVizza. I don't know how to help then. I never had problems with heroku env vars before. Can you see the variables if you run the ruby console in your staging environment?
`heroku run rails console`

Comment: Thanks @joao. I did try `heroku run rails console` however I get the same error as above when the carrierwave initializer is run.

Comment: You should be able to just do `heroku run irb` if you want, it won't load your app, but it will give you irb that you can look at ENV with (ditto for `heroku run bash`).

Comment: Thanks @geemus. The two ENV variables that are set from my carrierwave initializer are present when I check the ENV with `heroku run irb`...I wonder if there is an ordering issue with when the initializer is called compared to when ENV is set...?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variables in Heroku by following these instructions:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard

These will be accessible in the Rails code as `ENV['my_environment_variable_name']`, where `my_environment_variable_name` is the name of the environment variable that you enter in the Heroku Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when working on a **Rails 6** application in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

When I try to upload images to DigitalOcean Spaces (same thing as AWS S3 Bucket) I get the error:

> ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key

**Here's how I fixed it**:

My environment variables were properly set in my `.env` file.

The issue was that I had another `.env` file which was `.env.template` which had an incorrect value for `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`.

All I had to do was to delete the file. This time the Rails application was able to pick the values of the environment variables from the `.env` file.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**